# AngularJS prevent default select directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my case AngularJS's [`select`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect%20select) is not a good fit - (with `ng-repeat` approach `<option>` values can only be strings and with `ng-options` I can't properly set the initial selected value).

What can I do to stop angular from applying `select` directive everywhere he sees `<select>` element ?

The reason I am asking this question, is because I want to apply a custom directive on `select` element, that would perform something similar like the original one, so they would be conflicting.

Comment: Give us an example of what you are wanting to do in a code block. You can set the initial value with ng-model so I am not sure what is not working for you.

Comment: To simplify the question - how do I prevent default directives from getting applied ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="angularApp">
    <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
        <select ng-model="initialSelectedValue" ng-options="option for option in [1,2,3]"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
angular.module('angularApp', []);

function testCtrl($scope)
{
    $scope.initialSelectedValue = 2;
}
```

I created the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tadchristiansen/HM6SV/) for it.